# How in Delphi can I force an SQLite aggregate field to be a numeric field?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, types

We are converting a program written for MySQL to use SQLite. Some of the code adapts automatically to the type of fields we get back from the database. SQLite has the "interesting" property of present the SQL SUM(...) function as ftWideString (presumably to handle possible overflow). We need these fields to be integer or float fields. I tried this, which seems to obvious compel the SQL to give you the type you need:

```
SELECT cast(sum(units) as int) FROM dr02
```

but the type is still ftWideString.

How can I make it return an ftInteger or ftLargeInt, or ftFloat, as required?

Comment: By changing the property value?

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: See [Why is Delphi (Zeos) giving me widestring fields in SQLite when I ask for unsigned big int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689279/why-is-delphi-zeos-giving-me-widestring-fields-in-sqlite-when-i-ask-for-unsign/32689900#32689900)

Comment: I should have said: We are using  ZEOS 7.1.4 stable.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question I asked before. The previous one was about a particular type - unsigned big int, which becomes wide string. We can avoid that type and just using integer and get the results we want. But with aggregate functions we don't have that luxury. This is not why does it do it, but how can I make Delphi open the query in the type we need to make our existing software, which checks the types of fields, work.

Comment: @MarkAurelius The root cause is probably exactly the same: the TDataSet type is not the one of the query. In both cases, the column is an INTEGER (which is the same as BigInt for SQlite3), your TDataset returns erroneously ftWideString. If you solve previous question, I guess it would solve this one. I guess the answer would be the same: either upgrade to latest 7.2 branch of Zeos, or direclty use the ZDBC layer, and retrieve the type just before getting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT sum(units)*1.0 FROM dr02
```

or

```
SELECT cast(sum(units) as real) FROM dr02
```

You did not define which library you are using. Your question is highly linked to the library accessing SQLite3. A direct access (via [ZDBC/Zeos 7.2](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/) or [SynSQLite3](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynSQLite3.pas)) would allow to get the value directly with the expected type.

Comment: To ask for more information, use a comment.

Comment: I made two proposals, as answers.

Comment: You asked a question. (And they wouldn't work.)

Comment: Why wouldn't they work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613

Comment: Because whatever library is used determines the column type without looking at the values' types.

Comment: Yes I know. The OP is asking it twice. I already answered that last week. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689279/why-is-delphi-zeos-giving-me-widestring-fields-in-sqlite-when-i-ask-for-unsign/32689900#32689900 I thought he/she did understand the issue, and is looking for SQL level hints.

Comment: I tried  * 1.0 and casting as real. Both of those still come back as ftWideString, a field of class TWideStringField.

Comment: The DB library is ZEOS 7.1.4 stable.

Comment: @MarkAurelius Didn't you test with ZDBC 7.2 branch, as suggested in the previous answer?

Comment: No, we haven't installed that yet. We were able to solve our issue in the other question without installing any more components. But that may be the answer in this case.

Comment: @MarkAurelius How do you create the dataset? Try to force the column type.

Comment: If you mean doing cast in SQL, I have tried that. cast didn't change the type. For example:
SELECT cast(total(units) as int) FROM dr02
still gives us a field of type ftWideString. But since I said that in the opening question, maybe you have something else in mind?

This is done by passing a query to the SQL property of a TZQuery.

Comment: Did you execute the statement before getting the field type?