# How to get correct datatype of agregate field?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe5

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1] (
  [OrderNumber] integer, 
  [Amount] float 
);
```

Using `TSQLQuery` from dbExpress library.

```
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select sum(Amount) from Table1 group by OrderNumber';
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  SQLQuery1.First;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsFloat));
```

As a result, I get:

> Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Cannot access field 'Column0' as type Float'.

But if I trying to get value as `String`, there no error. It work:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsString);
```

How get data in `Float`?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814875/how-in-delphi-can-i-force-an-sqlite-aggregate-field-to-be-a-numeric-field  You could cast..

Comment: @JohnEasley I tried all that variants `select cast(sum(Amount) as float) from Table1...`, `select sum(Amount)*1.0  from Table1...` and so on, but got same error

Comment: Strange that the error references Column0 when you're using Column1. Have your tried `SELECT OrderNumber, sum(Amount) FROM Table1 Group by OrderNumber` so that the both columns are in the result set?

Comment: @JohnEasley There are no error in index of field. `SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsString` show right data but in wrong type

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to use this solution:

```
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'drop table if exists temp.agregatetable1;      ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'create temp table if not exists AgregateTable1 '+
  '(                                              '+
  '  [OrderNumber] integer,                       '+
  '  [SumAmount] float                            '+
  ');                                             ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'insert into Temp.AgregateTable1                '+
  'select                                         '+
  '     OrderNumber,                              '+
  '     sum(Amount)                               '+
  'from                                           '+
  '     Table1                                    '+
  'group by                                       '+
  '      OrderNumber;                             ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 
  'select SumAmount from Temp.AgregateTable1      ';
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  SQLQuery1.First;
  while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsFloat));
      SQLQuery1.Next;
    end;
```

But if someone knows a better way, I will be glad if you share it.