# TFDQuery and SQLite: Type mismatch for field, expecting: LargeInt actual: WideString

Tags: delphi, sqlite, teechart, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Using Delphi 10.2, SQLite and Teecharts. My SQLite database has two fields, created with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE HistoryRuntime ('DayTime' DateTime, Device1 INTEGER DEFAULT (0));
```

I access the table using a `TFDQuery` called `qryGrpahRuntime` with the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT DayTime AS TheDate, Sum(Device1) As DeviceTotal
FROM HistoryRuntime 
WHERE  (DayTime >= "2017-06-01") and (DayTime <= "2017-06-26") 
Group by Date(DayTime)
```

Using the Field Editor in the Delphi IDE, I can add two persistent fields, getting `TheDate` as a `TDateTimeField` and `DeviceTotal` as a `TLargeIntField`.

I run this query in a program to create a TeeChart, which I created at design time. As long as the query returns some records, all this works. However, if there are no records for the requested dates, I get an `EDatabaseError` exception with the message:

> qryGrpahRuntime: Type mismatch for field 'DeviceTotal', expecting: LargeInt actual: Widestring

I have done plenty of searching for solutions on the web on how to prevent this error on an empty query, but have had not luck with anything I found. From what I can tell, SQLite defaults to the wide string field when no data is returned. I have tried using CAST in the query and it did not seem to make any difference.

If I remove the persistent fields, the query will open without problems on an empty return set. However, in order to use the TeeChart editor in the IDE, it appears I need persistent fields.

Is there a way I can make this work with persistent fields, or am I going to have to throw out the persistent fields and then add the TeeChart Series at runtime?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32818322; there is no column type because the result column does not come directly from a table column. Apparently, there is no way to override that.

Comment: @CL, so if there is no way to override the column type once the query is open, is there anything I can do to tell if the query will be empty before I run it? Opening the query is where I get the error. I simply need to know if the query will be empty, then I can just not open the TeeChart, there by stopping the error.

Comment: FYI: I am using the Professional version without the FireDAC addon, so I do not have the source code to FireDac to research.

Comment: You could execute this query (or a simpler one) separately.

Comment: @CL, that is the way I am working around the problem right now. I am just selecting the Daytime value for the requested dates, then checking if that is empty before running the full query. Not the best way to do it, but everything else I have tried failed and this should work for my TeeChart forms at least.

Comment: The SQLite engine should throw [integer overflow](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) exception when the integer value overflows during `SUM` computation, so as it seems, `TIntegerField` should be enough here. Very interesting question, though. Could you please add [tag:delphi] and [tag:firedac] tags and include your attempt to `CAST`, please?

Comment: @Victoria, this isn't a problem with an overflow of the Sum calculation. It has to do with SQLite returning a Widestring field for the Sum calculation when the result set is empty, and a LargeInt field when the result set has data. So when using persistent fields, created in the IDE, you get a field mismatch with an empty set. Using CAST to return a LargeInt field regardless of whether the result set is empty or not doesn't work. It still returns a Widestring field if the set is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is described in [**Adjusting FireDAC Mapping**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Adjusting_FireDAC_Mapping) chapter of the FireDAC's SQLite manual:

> For an expression in a SELECT list, SQLite avoids type name
>   information. When the result set is not empty, FireDAC uses the value
>   data types from the first record. When empty, FireDAC describes those
>   columns as dtWideString. To explicitly specify the column data type,
>   append `::<type name>` to the column alias:
>
> `SELECT count(*) as "cnt::INT" FROM mytab`

So modify your command e.g. this way (I used **BIGINT**, but you can use any [**pseudo data type**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types) that maps to a 64-bit signed integer data type and is not  auto incrementing, which corresponds to your persistent [**TLargeIntField**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TLargeintField) field):

```sql
SELECT
   DayTime AS "TheDate",
   Sum(Device1) AS "DeviceTotal::BIGINT"
FROM
   HistoryRuntime 
WHERE
   DayTime BETWEEN {d 2017-06-01} AND {d 2017-06-26}
GROUP BY
   Date(DayTime)
```

P.S. I did a small optimization by using [**BETWEEN**](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) operator (which evaluates the column value only once), and used an [**escape sequence**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences) for date constants (which, in real you replace by parameter, I guess; so just for curiosity).

---

This data type hinting is parsed by the [**FDSQLiteTypeName2ADDataType**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.SQLite.FDSQLiteTypeName2ADDataType) procedure that takes and parses column name in format **<column name>::<type name>** in its **AColName** parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Victoria, that works, however I did have to change it to Sum(Device1) AS "DeviceTotal::BIGINT" in order for it to work

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Fixed.

Comment: I am using the Pro version, which doesn't come with the source for FireDAC, hence the lot of searching and finally the question here.

Comment: @Victoria: Another first-class answer which I missed at the time, +1